# JQuery - How to generate hierarchy with generated div and <select> tag

Tags: jquery, html

I have to do some forms and generate div with them but that's not my problem here.

Actually, I would like to know how create something like a hierarchy between this generated div, and the main actor will be the `<select>` tag.

[image]

Here  is an image of what I would like to have. For exemple when I create a chapter and I related it to the Book 1 I just generated before, then the chapter append inside the right "book" div. Or another example if I want to create a specific Line block. I want it in the right Chapter block itself in the right Book block.

I don't know if I'm very clear and precise, but here is my actual code on Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Uxrieg/hctr0xbh/16/

And my currently Jquery script :

```
$("#select").change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#select-choice > div").hide();
    $("." + val).slideToggle();
});

   $('#createBook').click(function(){
  var listItem = $('#bookName').val();
  var clearButton = $('<button value="x" id="clear"></button>');
  //console.log(listItem);
  $('#list').append('<div class= "BookName">' + listItem +'<input type=button class="item" value=X />'   + '</div>');
  $('#bookName').val(' ');
});

 $('#createChapter').click(function(){
  var listItem = $('#chapterName').val();
  var clearButton = $('<button value="x" id="clear"></button>');
  //console.log(listItem);
  $('#list').append('<div class= "ChapterName">' + listItem +'<input type=button class="item" value=X />'   + '</div>');
  $('#chapterName').val(' ');
});

$('#createLine').click(function(){
  var listItem = $('#lineName').val();
  var clearButton = $('<button value="x" id="clear"></button>');
  //console.log(listItem);
  $('#list').append('<div class= "LineName">' + listItem +'<input type=button class="item" value=X />'   + '</div>');
  $('#lineName').val(' ');
});

$(document).on('click', '.BookName', function(){
  //console.log('clicked');
  $(this).remove();
});

$(document).on('click', '.ChapterName', function(){
  //console.log('clicked');
  $(this).remove();
});

$(document).on('click', '.LineName', function(){
  //console.log('clicked');
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Thanks a lot in advance, if you can solve my problem or just help me. Have a good day ! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the selector in the append calls to chapter and line:

`$('.BookName', '#list').append('<div class= "ChapterName">' + listItem +'<input type=button class="item" value=X />'   + '</div>');`

`$('.ChapterName', '#list').append('<div class= "LineName">' + listItem +'<input type=button class="item" value=X />'   + '</div>');`

Keep in mind that if no book has been created, then adding chapter/lines won't do anything, also if no chapters have been created then adding lines won't do anything. This code will create a new chapter within all opened books or a new line within all created chapters. If you need to be more specific then you need to add more logic and change your selectors.

More about jquery selectors here: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/